# can't remove Read Only + cmd not working

Tags: windows-10, permissions, cmd.exe, read-only

My windows files and folder in my laptop is turned to read only

[image]

i tried   : 
`Right-click the folder > Properties
Security tab > Advanced
Click Change to the right of Owner
Enter Users into box and click OK
Enable the checkbox Replace owner on subcontainers and objects then click Apply
If prompted that You do not have permissions to read... click Yes
Completely close out of the Advanced Security Settings dialog
Right-click the folder > Properties
Security tab > Edit...
Add...
Enter Users into box and click OK
Enable the Full Control checkbox then click OK`

but nothing happens i also noticed that cmd commands not working ..

[image]

thanks

the output of %path% :

```
C:\Users\Kareem Khalil>echo %path%
;c:\\C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR;;c:\\C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR;C:\Program Files (x86)\BC5\BIN;C:\Users\Kareem Khalil\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\New Folder;C:\New Folder
```

Comment: What is the output from `echo %path%`?

Comment: Note that for folders, the "read only" flag just means that Explorer should treat it slightly differently when it comes to UI.

Answer (score 0):

#### Windows commands are not working

```
C:\Users\Kareem Khalil>echo %path%
;c:\\C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR;;c:\\C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR;C:\Program Files (x86)\BC5\BIN;C:\Users\Kareem Khalil\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\New Folder;C:\New Folder
```

Your path is completely broken:

- It is missing essential entries for Windows executables (which is why you commands are not working)
- It should not contain `\\` entries
- It should not contain repeated entries
- It should not contain entries containing strings like `c:\\C:\`
- It should not contain `;;` entries

The correct (default) path on Windows 10 (and previous versions of Windows) is:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```

See [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them) for instructions on how to fix your `PATH` to the correct value I have shown above.

Answer (score 0):

In windows 10 there's a secondary option which may work instead of CMD its called PowerShell. Just follow instructions for that. Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, "follow the instructions" isn't a supremely useful answer in its own right. Could you please [edit] your answer to include how to actually accomplish the task?